# What is the different between Ajax and Web Worker in Javascript?

Tags: ajax, web-worker

I think they almost do the same thing.
What's the condition that we should choose Web Worker than Ajax?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AJAX is specifically for communicating with a server, whereas web workers are a for background processing.

While AJAX is asynchronous (by default), this is not to be confused with a "concurrent" model of background processing that web workers offer.

A web worker could be *any* process and is not restricted to client-server communication.

Comment: Can I say, they are the same thing in client-server communication?

Comment: No. For example, web workers could be used for something like an animation engine, something that has nothing to do with server communication.

Comment: You would still use AJAX within a web worker. The web worker is not a communications tool.